# Value in Roundslider range not centerd

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, range, round-slider

I'm making a round range slider with the Roundslider jQuery plugin. Everything works fine, but the value that's inside the round range input is not centred in it's first state. As soon as you interact with the handle the value is centred inside the circle. Here the two states:

**First, on load state:**

[image]

**After interacting with the handle:**

[image: After interacting]

I've been playing around inside the Roundslider plugin JavaScript files for a while now, but can't find the problem. Is there anyone who had this problem as well and knows a fix for it?

Hope someone can help, thanks in advance.

Btw; posting code is not relevant in this case I guess, but let me know if it would help.

Comment: Can you let me know the roundSlider plugin's version that you are using. Since in the latest version 1.3 the problem doesn't exists.

Comment: @camile, is the issue resolved now?